# How would this date formula be structured? End Date = Start Date + Length in months)

Tags: formula, opportunity, fields, date

I'm looking to auto-populate my End date field in the Opportunity Object.

I have Start Date, End Date, and Opportunity Length (in months).

Please help? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use date formula field for your  use as suggested by CaspNZ

here is the answer for other person's reference

```
DATE( Year([start date])+floor((MONTH([start date]) + [# of months] - 1) / 12) , 

    mod(MONTH([start date]) + [# of months] -1, 12) + 1 , 

     day([start date])
) - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that all months are 30 days long, it's reasonably easy.
You would define the formula as:

```
End_Date = Start_Date + (Opportunity_Length*30)
```

If you need something that takes into account the length of each month, then it's quite a bit harder.

Comment: I actually found the answer, but thanks so much!

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gymAAAQ

Comment: That's definitely better than mine. You should post it as an answer here for posterity.